# Checkbox Required attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, input

Hi I've been using this code for my checkbox, and I want something like before clicking any button(link) you should click the checkbox first. What seems to be the problem? or what am I lacking in the code

```
//check box EULA
sb.Append("<br/><input type='checkbox' name='eula' required='true' /> By clicking Accept, you confirm that you are ready to proceed with this purchase, have read the terms and conditions, that you understand them, and that you agree to be bound by them. Please expect an invoice soon after.<br>");

// this contains message description w/ name
sb.Append("<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%;'><tr><td width='260' valign='top'> <br><br></td><td style='font-size: 0; line-height: 0;' width='20'> &nbsp;</td><td width='260' valign='top'><div style='float:right;'><br>");

//buttons
string accept_link = Url.Action("AcceptQuotation", "ServiceRequest", new { id = serviceRequest.EmailHash }, Request.Url.Scheme);
string decline_link = Url.Action("DeclineQuotation", "ServiceRequest", new { id = serviceRequest.EmailHash }, Request.Url.Scheme);
string comment_link = Url.Action("CommentQuotation", "ServiceRequest", new { id = serviceRequest.EmailHash }, Request.Url.Scheme);

sb.Append("<a href='" + accept_link + "' style='cursor:pointer; padding:1vh; padding-left:3vh; padding-right:3vh; border-style:none; background-color:#7AC142; color:white; text-decoration:none; margin-right:10px;'>Accept</a>");
sb.Append("<a href='" + decline_link + "' style='cursor:pointer; padding:1vh; padding-left:3vh; padding-right:3vh; border-style:none; background-color:#EE6363; color:white; text-decoration:none; margin-right:10px;'>Decline</a>");
sb.Append("<a href='" + comment_link + "' style='cursor:pointer; padding:1vh; padding-left:3vh; padding-right:3vh; border-style:none; background-color:#4badff; color:white; text-decoration:none;'>Comment</a>");

sb.Append("</div></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td><table border = '0' cellpadding = '0' cellspacing = '0' width = '100%' ><tr><td colspan='4' bgcolor='#F3AD61' style='padding:3vh; text-align:center; color:white;'> Connect with Full Suite</td></tr><tr bgcolor='#F3AD61'><td style='padding-left:90px; padding-right:20px;'> <a target='_blank' href='https://www.facebook.com/fullsuite/' style='text-decoration:none; float:right;'> <img src='http://full-suite.azurewebsites.net/Content/Images/Email/fb.png' width='40' /> </a></td><td style='padding-left:0px;'> <a target='_blank' href='https://www.instagram.com/fullsuite/' style='text-decoration:none;'> <img src='http://full-suite.azurewebsites.net/Content/Images/Email/ig.png' width='40' /> </a></td><td style='padding-left:0px;'> <a target='_blank' href='https://www.linkedin.com/company/fullsuite' style='text-decoration:none;'> <img src='http://full-suite.azurewebsites.net/Content/Images/Email/li.png' width='40' /> </a></td><td style='padding-right:100px;'> <a target='_blank' href='https://twitter.com/fullsuite?lang=en' style='text-decoration:none;'> <img src='http://full-suite.azurewebsites.net/Content/Images/Email/tw.png' width='40' /> </a></td></tr ><tr><td colspan='4' bgcolor='#F3AD61' height='25'></td></tr></table ></td></tr></table></table></body></html>");
```

Comment: Why don't you use model with Boolean property and annotation on it? Why would use string builder to render html in the view?

Comment: because I'm building it for an email body, is there anyway on how to make it required using this format?

Comment: because the required attribute doesnt work even if I put " required = "true" " already

Comment: Not sure how would you make it require in email body. Normal requirement would be to have checkbox in a form and have a submit button and a JavaScript which will be executed before form is submitted to check if checkbox is checked. Depending on the email client, JavaScript may be allowed to run or not. So having validation in email might not be a 100% working solution. I would suggest to redirect user to your application page where you can have your way of validation to force user to accept EULA before proceeding.